# When consuming WCF through IIS its connecting to another database instead of the one in connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, iis-7

This question can be weird but i tried my best to find a solution but i am not able to.

I created a WCF service which will return an object with the help of a `sql function`. There is a connection string in the WCF to connect to SQL SERVER and its connecting to `mydatabase_uat`. The sql function is 
`my_function` when I run it locally it is executing perfectly and giving the result.

I deployed the same in `IIS7`. Then Wrote another consuming application which consume the same WCF. Then I got an error.

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "dbo.my_function", or the name is ambiguous

I have another database `mydatabase_live`. For checking i created the same function `my_function` in `mydatabase_live`. After that the WCF consuming application works perfectly.

So the consuming application is pointing to `mydatabase_live` but the connection string in WCF is to  `my_database_uat`

I am not understanding why this is happening. Anybody here gone through this issue?

Note: There is no connection string in consuming application

Comment: I've had this issue once before and then realized that the program did overwrite the `new context()` method with a different connectionstring than the one in config-file. is this only Happening when you published your WCF on IIS or also in debug-Environment?

Comment: @MarcelB when WCF debug-Environment its fine.. connecting to correct database..but after published in IIS and accessing it through another application problem occurs